# No module named 'PIL' but requirement Pillow already satisfied

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I'm trying use Image from PIL but when i run my script file it says,

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "script.py", line 12, in 
>       from PIL import Image
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'

But i can see that Pillow 5.0.0 is install when i list all modules using pip list.

i have already searched for solutions but most of them point out to install Pillow, which i already have! what am i doing wrong?

I have a script file to download images from internet it uses Pillow, i  have tried all known solutions but they all point to install pillow again and again.

```
import sys, os, multiprocessing, urllib, csv
from io import StringIO
from PIL import Image


def ParseData(data_file):
 csvfile = open(data_file, 'r')
 csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
 key_url_list = [line[:2] for line in csvreader]
 return key_url_list[1:]  # Chop off header


def DownloadImage(key_url):
 out_dir = sys.argv[2]
 (key, url) = key_url
 filename = os.path.join(out_dir, '%s.jpg' % key)

if os.path.exists(filename):
 print('Image %s already exists. Skipping download.' % filename)
 return

try:
 response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
 image_data = response.read()
except:
 print('Warning: Could not download image %s from %s' % (key, url))
 return

try:
 pil_image = Image.open(StringIO(image_data))
except:
 print('Warning: Failed to parse image %s' % key)
 return

try:
 pil_image_rgb = pil_image.convert('RGB')
except:
 print('Warning: Failed to convert image %s to RGB' % key)
 return

try:
 pil_image_rgb.save(filename, format='JPEG', quality=90)
except:
 print('Warning: Failed to save image %s' % filename)
 return


def Run():
 if len(sys.argv) != 3:
  print('Syntax: %s <data_file.csv> <output_dir/>' % sys.argv[0])
  sys.exit(0)
 (data_file, out_dir) = sys.argv[1:]

if not os.path.exists(out_dir):
 os.mkdir(out_dir)

key_url_list = ParseData(data_file)
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=50)
pool.map(DownloadImage, key_url_list)


if __name__ == '__main__':
 Run()
```

Comment: Well then use PILLOW!

Comment: Can you show us what `pip freeze` shows you? Does that contain `pillow==5.0.0`

Comment: Yes mate my pip freeze contains Pillow==5.0.0

Comment: @ᴡʜᴀᴄᴋᴀᴍᴀᴅᴏᴏᴅʟᴇ3000 `pip install PILLOW
Requirement already satisfied: PILLOW in c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages`

Comment: Can you try just "import Image" instead of what you have currently.

Comment: Try this: `sudo pip install Pillow`, not all caps.

Comment: @ hikerjobs `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 11, in <module>
    import sys, os, multiprocessing, urllib, csv,Image
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Image'`

Comment: @ᴡʜᴀᴄᴋᴀᴍᴀᴅᴏᴏᴅʟᴇ3000 `pip install Pillow
Requirement already satisfied: Pillow in c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages`

Comment: Can you post some code snippets? Also, which version of Python are you using?

Comment: @hikerjobs Code updated in question, my py version `python -V
Python 3.6.3 :: Anaconda custom (64-bit)`

Comment: You may need to install Pillow with pip3 instead of pip. Check 'pip3 freeze' and see if you see Pillow.

Comment: `sudo pip3 install Pillow`

Comment: `sudo pip3 install PILLOW` or whatever you spell it as.

Comment: @hikerjobs there is no pip3 in anaconda only pip, i have tried to upgrade and and install. But still no results

Comment: try `conda install pillow`

Comment: @venky__ already tried mate `# All requested packages already installed.`

Comment: Seems like you might have issues with the different versions of Python. See this documentation - https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-python.html?highlight=python#installing-a-different-version-of-python

Comment: do you get the same error when trying to run import in python shell?

Answer (score 0):

Asked my friend for help on this matter as he's a python dev! So he said anaconda latest on windows is unstable and recommended to use anaconda on Linux. So i tried in Fedora workstation and then i didn't face any problem.